# How to protect swift code with framework or static lib?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, frameworks, static-libraries

Usually we can protect source code implementation by wrapping into static lib or dynamic lib, or framework with open header files etc.

For swift, I got knowing that "swift does not support static lib".

Does this mean there is no way to protect swift source code by such legacy lib way ?

Question here is to clarify this and find out the approach.

Thanks,

Comment: doesnt seem like there is any way at the moment, probably have to just stick to obj-c for your static lib if protecting your code is that important. at least you can use obj-c in your swift projects

Comment: you mean use obj-c to write the static lib for protection this moment ? why swift does not support this , so weird ! even java provide some jar way to protect source code from some level...

Comment: yeah, i saw some comments about it that since swift is still basically under development, they dont want libs being made and then breaking each time they make changes (and not being updated in a timely fashion), so maybe it will come later when its more stable